# Getting Japanese fonts (hiragana & katakana) and entering text into LibreOffice (NB Not changing entire system language to Japanese) Qu Pt 2

Tags: software-installation

Following Goldilocks guidance, I seem to have a series of fonts installed but can find nothing to say/show how they might be 'activated' and input swapped between English letters and Japanese syllables.
Rebooting doesn't help.

Anyone anymore ideas/suggestions pls?

Comment: What guidance? Can you give a link? But please edit your question to update it, not making a comment.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you've tried and already done? It also seems like this might be better suited as an edit to your original question.